# Chrome Extension example of oAuth 2.0

Tags: google-chrome-extension, oauth-2.0

The chrome developer extension tutorials use an outdated oAuth 1 that will be phased out in April 2015: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_oauth

Is there a tutorial of implementing oAuth 2.0 inside a chrome extension?

Comment: Bulk, seriously the internet is larger than the first results of google. Knowledgeable people could point out golden results otherwise not found through a query.

Comment: I for one am glad you asked this question, upvoted. Also, that's one deep sentence :D - "Bulk, seriously the internet is larger than the first results of google."

Comment: @cDima While searching for information on doing oauth2 calls from an extension I landed back on this page (from a google result). I had totally forgotten I said what I said and 1. I feel like a total idiot, and 2. owe you an apology. I don't want to make excuses so I'll just say clearly you didn't deserve my comment, and I'm very sorry for it.

Comment: @bulk all good my friend ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right answer was to use [Google Identity api](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/identity), which under the covers uses oAuth 2.0 endpoints to [https://.chromiumapp.org/* urls](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/identity#method-launchWebAuthFlow).

Comment: This method requires the user to be signed in to Chrome

Comment: I up voted the question but down voted the answer: [the link](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_oauth) you used in your answer is an _actual_ tutorial.. with code examples and all.. your answer simply pointed to some api call.. with very sparse documentation. Your own question was _Is there a tutorial of implementing oAuth 2.0 inside a chrome extension?_ this answer didn't offer one

Comment: Agreed with @abbood

Answer (score 16):

I've written an example of how to [integrate any OAuth2 system into a Chrome extension](https://github.com/michaeloryl/oauth2-angularjs-chrome-extension-demo).  My extension uses AngularJS as the framework, but you could do it in plain old JavaScript or some other framework if you so choose by following the same patterns.

The trick is to use the `chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow()` method.

My example is actually configured to use Google, but that's merely because it is convenient.  You can use your own OAuth2 provider, as I do at my company.  The important distinctions are that `launchWebAuthFlow()` doesn't require the browser to be logged into Google the way the `chrome.identity.getAuthToken()` method would, and that you can use it with non-Google OAuth2 systems.

Comment: Hey Michael, how you get a new token after the previous expires?

Comment: This grant type does not allow for refresh tokens.  Once the session/token expires, you need to re-authenticate the user.  Allowing refresh tokens to be given to code that lives in the browser would open up a number of security holes.

Comment: Might as well use `getAuthToken()` instead of `launchWebAuthFlow()` since I need the user to login with their internal G Suite account and with the former you can get a fresh token by calling it again if they're logged into Chrome with account they're authorizing in the extension — which is also a bummer but can't think of any other method in order to get a refresh token.

Comment: Michael, there's actually a way you can use to get a new token with `launchWebAuthFlow()` see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51385987/4932334

Comment: @MichaelOryl I'm using chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow(), but my extension is not published, so i can not get callback. I checked the document, but do not find anythings for local enviroment.

Answer (score 3):

I personally find the Chrome Identity API hard to use. Maybe it's because the documentation is poorly written or because Google is only straightforward about doing authentication against their own services.

I found an old library that does most of the OAuth dance and the required injections pretty well. 
I did some cleaning and extended the API. You can find it here: https://github.com/whoisjuan/ChromeAuth2

Answer (score 2):

At this point, you may need to add `"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts"` in `manifest.json`

```
....
"oauth2": {
    "client_id": "[Your Client Id]",
    "scopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts"]
  }
....
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).