# Chrome Extension Integration with oAuth 2.0

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, oauth-2.0, google-api-client, google-oauth

The problem is that the oath [tutorial](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_oauth) provided by Google with chrome extension is outdated (and seems to deal with oAuth not oAuth 2.0)

An almost identical question to this was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28330902/chrome-extension-example-of-oauth-2-0), however the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28349790/766570) simply provided an api reference, no tutorial.

I'm looking for an official (or non-official.. as long as it counts as a tutorial) for oAuth 2.0 integration with chrome extensions. Lacking that, if someone can simply give me a road map of links/tutorials where I can start at some point and reach that destination.

(Googling shows me articles like [this one](http://smus.com/oauth2-chrome-extensions/).. which is dated 2011, which is pretty a millennia ago)

Comment: You can use chrome.identity API : https://developer.chrome.com/apps/identity

Comment: identity api has important limitations.

Comment: @ZigMandel Please tell me more

Comment: for starters, it requires the user to be signed in to chrome. most users dont.

Comment: @ZigMandel my application is a B2B app that requires users be signed in chrome. Anything else?

Comment: nothing else if you are doing oauth with google scopes only, and that it will always use the chrome account, even if the user is signed in (on web pages) under multiple Google accounts

Comment: Have you got any good answer? Please share the solution.

Answer (score 0):

There's a tutorial on using OAuth2 with your Chrome Extension here: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_identity

Comment: this isn't chrome extension.. this is chrome apps.. which will soon be deprecated