# How can I authenticate a multiple google users for a chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-oauth

I'm building a gmail chrome extension that requires pulling data specific to each account. I initially used the code below but soon realized that it will not work for multiple accounts (e.g. personal vs work account)

```
chrome.identity.getAuthToken(
    {'interactive': false},
    function(){
       //load Google's javascript client libraries
       console.log("getAuthToken");
       window.gapi_onload = authorize;
       loadScript('https://apis.google.com/js/client.js');
    }
);
```

I've tried searching online but couldn't find any code samples. I know I've to implement OAuth2 however Google's OAuth Tutorial is outdated. What's the best way for me to authenticate a different user when I switch gmail apps?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_identity), you may use the [Chrome Identity API](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/identity) to authenticate users: the `getAuthToken` for users logged into their Google Account and the `launchWebAuthFlow` for users logged into a non-Google account. If your app uses its own server to authenticate users, you will need to use the latter.

Here are the five steps you need to complete for Google account authentication:

- Add permissions to your manifest and upload your app.
- Copy key in the installed `manifest.json` to your source manifest, so that your application ID will stay constant during development.
- Get an OAuth2 client ID for your Chrome App.
- Update your manifest to include the client ID and scopes.
- Get the authentication token.

Additional reference: [Chrome Extension example of oAuth 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28330902/chrome-extension-example-of-oauth-2-0)

Hope this helps.