# How do I get a new Access Token before its expiration after user login with chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Sorry if this have been asked before but I've spend the whole day googling without any results.

I'm using Chrome Identity API for a Chrome Extension I'm building for my work (interacting with Google Sheets API), and I'm looking to persist the login for the user but refresh tokens with this API are nowhere to be found.

I first implemented `chrome.identity.getAuthToken()` and I was able to authorize the request to gSheets API, the problem came when the Access Token expired. I'm aware that calling `getAuthToken()` again refreshes the token if you call it with `interactive: false`, but only if the [People](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2364824?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop) you're logged in with has the same email you authorized in the initial interaction with the popup, and this is not what I want simply because in my browser I'm logged with my personal email, and I want to authorize the work email for the extension. So, after 1 hour I need to request a new token which will prompt a login popup and this is a poor user experience.

Then I tried with `chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow()` with the endpoint https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth knowing that `launchWebAuthFlow()` is for non-Google accounts, and even though it worked well, as far as I know, there is no way to refresh the token after — let's say — 45 minutes to avoid kicking out the user.

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
  switch (request.type) {
    case "login":
      let authURL = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth";
      const clientId = `<CLIENT_ID>`;
      const redirectURL = chrome.identity.getRedirectURL("oauth2");
      const auth_params = {
        client_id: clientId,
        redirect_uri: redirectURL,
        response_type: "token",
        scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"
      };

      const paramString = Object.keys(auth_params)
        .map(function(k) {
          return k + "=" + auth_params[k];
        })
        .join("&");

      authURL += "?" + paramString;

      chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow(
        { url: authURL, interactive: true },
        function(responseURL) {
          if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
            console.log(chrome.runtime.lastError);
            return;
          }

          if (responseURL) {
            const paramsString = responseURL.substring(
              responseURL.indexOf("#") + 1
            );
            const params = new URLSearchParams(paramsString);

            const paramsObj = () => {
              const obj = {};
              for (var entry of params.entries()) {
                obj[entry[0]] = entry[1];
              }
              return obj;
            };

            const { access_token } = paramsObj();

            sendResponse({
              access_token
            });
          } else {
            console.log(`${responseURL} defined?`);
          }
        }
      );

      return true;
    default:
      console.log("placeholder");
      break;
      }
});
```

I'm willing to ditch Chrome Identity API and use another OAuth2 flow if it means I can improve the user experience for the user.

TL;DR: I want to get a new access token either with Chrome Identity API or any other OAuth2 implementation a few minutes before the previous token expires, while being able to use a Google Account different than the logged in Chrome (People).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I could've edited the previous question, but instead I'm going to answer it:

There's a way to get a new token by issuing a code instead of a token using
`access_type=offline` and `response_type:'code'`.

```
let authURL = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth';
const redirectURL = chrome.identity.getRedirectURL("oauth2");
const auth_params = {
  client_id: clientId,
  redirect_uri: redirectURL,
  response_type: 'code',
  access_type: 'offline',
  scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',
};
chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow({url: authURL, interactive: true}, responseURL => console.log(responseURL))
```

The response will be a URL:

`https://<extension_id>.chromiumapp.org/oauth2?code=4/A<code>#`

The code returned can be redeemed for a token that can be used only 1 time. You then send a POST request to `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token` with the following snippet as the request:

```
POST /oauth2/v4/token HTTP/1.1
Host: www.googleapis.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

code=4/A<code>&
client_id=your_client_id&
client_secret=your_client_secret&
redirect_uri=https://<extension_id>.chromiumapp.org/oauth2&
grant_type=authorization_code
```

The response will be a JSON object which you can use for ~1 hour to make requests to Google APIs:

```
{
    "access_token": "<access_token>",
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_in": 3578
}
```

Finally before the access token expires you can call `launchWebAuthFlow()` with `interactive: false` and it will return a new code and with that you get a new token.

Comment: Do you place the call to the Google Token endpoint from the extension? I assume this is actually supposed to happen from the backend of your app?

Comment: Isn't putting client_secret in the extension code a security breach? Since the extension would be running on the client side, any malicious user would be able to read you both client_id and client_secret.

Comment: @Utkarsh Yes, you typically send a request to your own server and return the access token to the client.

Answer (score 3):

To get a new token by a code is the wrong way. Instead, a refresh token is designed to get a new token after the old one expired.

1. Exchange a code for refresh and access tokens.

   ```
   https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server?hl=en#exchange-authorization-code
   ```
2. Save the refresh token. When the current access token expires, get a new token by the refresh token.

   ```
   https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server?hl=en#offline
   ```

Good luck to coding.